# Circuit rewriting

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to find the current flowing through the 2 ohm resistor in the circuit labeled (A).
To do this, I tried to rewrite the circuit entirely but I think I got it wrong at (C).
I know I have to use Kirchhoff's laws, but I simply don't know where to start.
Thank you for any help

[image: Circuits]

Comment: You've got your signs wrong. The 8V and 12V are in series giving 20V. And I think your transformation for C is completely bogus.

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow, I checked, my signs are correct in the first circuit (A). How could I fix my transformation for (C) then? Can I not add up the voltages ?

Comment: By doing a Norton-Thevenin Transformation from B you should get what you're looking for as then everything is in parallel. You'll have -3A and +8/6A that are devided into the three resistors.

Comment: The basic steps can be reduced to only: Use superposition on your curcuit B to find only \$I_4{_\Omega}\$ and \$I_6{_\Omega}\$ . Mark the two resulting currents and their proper directions on the circuit.  \$I_2{_\Omega}\$ then becomes quite obvious, (by the current law).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEHRHb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Your transformation to B seems fine. From there it should be simple to calculate x using V = I * R and solving for x.

Since I suspect this might be homework just one last hint: Assume I1 = I2 + I3. The current flowing through R1 is the sum of the current flowing through R2 and R3 (and x < 12V).

Be careful of the direction the current is flowing in that scenario. If it later turns out x > 12V then one of I1, I2 or I3 will be negative. Which just means the current across that resistor flows the other way than assumed. The result will still be valid.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'm going to try what you suggested, an I'll validate the answer